# Data Parallelism in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, data-science, spacy

I have written a parser that parses the sentences in a large corpus (900,000 paragraphs) into constituency parse trees. The parser works by converting each paragraph into a list of constituency parse trees. Here is a general idea of the code:

```
paragraphs = load_dataset()
trees = list(map(parse_trees, paragraphs))
```

I have tried using python's `multiprocessing` and used the `pool` feature:

```
paragraphs = load_dataset()
p = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
trees = p.map(parse_trees, paragraphs)
```

What I noticed is that using `multiprocess` makes the task slower than not using it.

Upon further research, I realized that there is a difference between task parallelism and data parallelism, and I think that in my situation, data parallelism is more suitable.

I cannot quite find any methods in python to do this however, and was wondering if anybody could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.  Asking for off-site resources is specifically listed as out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: What you are doing with `multiprocessing.Pool.map` *is data parallelism*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `multiprocessing.Pool.map` is always significantly slower than map whenever i use it though.

Comment: @LukeYeh yes, well, are you aware of what multiprocessing does? It starts several differet *python interpreter processes*. Any data is copied, pickled, sent over to the other process, and deserialized. If the work each individual process is doing isn't worth that overhead, then you won't see any performance gains. You haven't shown what `parse_trees` does. But you are already using data-parallelism

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the `parse_trees` function essentially parses a paragraph into constituency parse trees. I am using a parser that I found on github https://github.com/nikitakit/self-attentive-parser. It takes around 5 seconds to parse a single paragraph on its own without multiprocessing, which I think is definitely worth the overhead.